# Video tearing on Samsung Smart TV HLS player

Tags: media-player, samsung-smart-tv

I'm building a Samsung Smart TV app that streams HLS video to the in-built HLS player.

All works well, except that I almost always see the video tearing about 20-30 seconds into playback.  It appears that the player initially selects a very low bitrate stream, then 'tears' as it adapts upwards.

I've tried setting the BITRATES parameter (specified http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/reference/url_parameters_for_has.html) in various ways but unfortunately the m3u8 files I receive vary so much in bandwidth parameter that I can't find a setting that works for all of them and solves my issue.  I also find that the player crashes more often when I have BITRATES set.

I've also tried experimenting with the UPTIMER parameter, but I don't really understand what it does.  According to the documentation it 'Specifies the threshold of the initial UP switching time which applies to switching between streams in different groups' but that still doesn't help me.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  If so, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the video tearing in the emulator or the TV?

About m3u8 write the url i.e "http://mydomain.com/playlist.m3u8" like this

"http://mydomain.com/playlist.m3u8|COMPONENT=HLS".

Comment: The video tears on the TV.

I have been using my URL with '|COMPONENT=HLS'.  If I don't my HLS stream doesn't play.

Comment: I have created my app with help of this tutorial and It's working.check this http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/javascript/play_audio_video/tut_js_video_has_intro.html

Comment: Hi Miso, can you upload your code again, i also have a same problem working with HLS streaming.

Comment: Is there any working samsung smart tv app that allow you paste a m3u8 url or rtmp stream and it plays it on tv?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old thread, but in case you are still wondering or anyone else is looking for the same answer.

I have recently started working on a commercials Samsung Smart TV app which plays the same type of streaming and what I ended up was entering a |STARTBITRATE= very high number 20000000 or 20 milion. In the sdk, the guys are saying that you could use HIGHEST, but it did not worked for me, so the higher number is the starting point and it starts looking for the nearest, which hopefully is the best quality you could have, to start with.

Cheers